# How to send parameters from Power Apps to Power Automate Flow

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I'm kind of new in PowerApp, and I've already create a power automate flow that ask for a parameter that works perfect in the flow process, it returns a list of data and it's what I want. Now I want to use the flow in my PowerApp application, which I've already added.

**Screen - onVisible**

```
Set(myData, 'MyFirstFlow'.Run("123"));
```

This flow on power automate with that parameter works fine, but in my powerApp application, I'm getting "false" when I want to check the data from "MyData".

```
ExpectResult: myData.id 
ExpectResult: myData.description
```

Am I doing something wrond in the way that I'm recollecting the data from the flow in my app?

Answer (score 1):

Issue seems to be with the Power Automate and not with the PowerApp.

Just make sure that the last step of the PowerAutomate is **"Response"**
If that doesn't work that I would suggest to try below two option

- Create a new flow and try again
- Copy any existing flow which is working fine and modify the steps.

Comment: Thanks @Aakash, I've just realized that I forgot to add the schema type in the response, that's the reason why, power app didn't complete any attribute.